# Pandas - Updating columns if several conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am aiming to the below output.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | 8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | AB1 | 1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | CD1 | -1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | EF1 | -4 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | GH1 | -1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | IL1 | 5 | first three-four col and offset |
| 3333 | CCC | 789 | MN1 | 2 | first two col and offset |
| 3333 | CCC | 101 | MN1 | -2 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 121 | UYT | 6 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 131 | FB1 | -5 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 141 | UYT | -1 | first two col and offset |
| 5555 | EEE | 151 | CB1 | 3 | first two col and offset |
| 5555 | EEE | 161 | CR1 | -3 | first two col and offset |
| 6666 | FFF | 111 | CB1 | 4 | first or no match |
| 7777 | GGG | 222 | ZB1 | 10.5 | first three-four col and small offset |
| 7777 | GGG | 222 | ZB1 | -10 | first three-four col and small offset |

1st rule) the first three columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination must have the associated numbers (col E) offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined).

2nd rule) the first two columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination must have the associated numbers (col E) offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined).

3rd rule) no match.

4th rule) the first three columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination can have a difference of `0.5` AT MOST (col E) and NO offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined).

Please see my code below.

I am fully aware of the fact that I haven't written the code in the most efficient way. Would you be able to advise a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (df['A'][i] == df['A'][j]) & (df['B'][i] == df['B'][j]) & (df['C'][i] == df['C'][j]) & (df['E'][i] + df['E'][j] == 0) :
            df['E'][i] = 'first three-four col and offset'
            df['E'][j] = 'first three-four col and offset'


for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (df['A'][i] == df['A'][j]) & (df['B'][i] == df['B'][j]) & (df['E'][i] + df['E'][j] == 0) & (df['E'][i] != 'first three-four col and offset') & (df['E'][j] != 'first three-four col and offset'):
            df['E'][i] = 'first two col and offset'
            df['E'][j] = 'first two col and offset'


for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (df['A'][i] == df['A'][j]) & (df['B'][i] == df['B'][j]) & (df['C'][i] == df['C'][j]) & (df['E'][i] + df['E'][j] != 0) & (df['E'][i] + df['E'][j] =< 0.5) & (df['E'][i] + df['E'][j] >= -0.5) & (df['E'][i] != 'first three-four col and offset') & (df['E'][j] != 'first three-four col and offset') & (df['E'][i] != 'first two col and offset') & (df['E'][j] != 'first two col and offset'):
            df['E'][i] = 'first three-four col and small offset'
            df['E'][j] = 'first three-four col and small offset'
```

Is there a way to have the expected result, in a more efficient way?

I am also aware that the following code does not work. I tried updating this record with the right comment in vain.

```
for ... :
  if.... :
     df['col'][index] = 'comment'
```

Let's further suppose that I wanted to leave my code in this "not-efficient way", which seems to be working (excepted for this last line of code). How should I change this last row to have my script working?

Comment: Have you checked out pd.DataFrame.where()? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html. It also helps to see the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `transform` and `np.select`

```
m1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform('sum').eq(0)  # Rule 1
m2 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['E'].transform('sum').eq(0)  # Rule 2
m3 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform('sum').abs().le(0.5)  # Rule 4

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['first three-four col and offset',
                      'first two col and offset', 'first three-four col and small offset'], 'first or no match')
```

---

```
       A    B    C    D     E                                      F                                    new
0   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1   8.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
1   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1  -8.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
2   1111  AAA  123  AB1   1.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
3   1111  AAA  123  CD1  -1.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
4   2222  BBB  456  EF1  -4.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
5   2222  BBB  456  GH1  -1.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
6   2222  BBB  456  IL1   5.0        first three-four col and offset        first three-four col and offset
7   3333  CCC  789  MN1   2.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
8   3333  CCC  101  MN1  -2.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
9   4444  DDD  121  UYT   6.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
10  4444  DDD  131  FB1  -5.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
11  4444  DDD  141  UYT  -1.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
12  5555  EEE  151  CB1   3.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
13  5555  EEE  161  CR1  -3.0               first two col and offset               first two col and offset
14  6666  FFF  111  CB1   4.0                      first or no match                      first or no match
15  7777  GGG  222  ZB1  10.5  first three-four col and small offset  first three-four col and small offset
16  7777  GGG  222  ZB1 -10.0  first three-four col and small offset  first three-four col and small offset
```